# Couldn't police find the IP address used to steal money in The Invisible Guest?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-guest

In the movie *"The Invisible Guest"* Laura uses her laptop to steal money from the bank to make it look like Daniel did it.

So couldn't the police track the IP address of Laura with that? Also couldn't police use mobile phone location tracking of Laura and Adrian to know where they were during the time of murder?